# Трансляция текста

Tags: транслятор

Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно написать трансляцию текста? Что-то вроде, на одной странице вводим текст, а на другой он выводится без обновления страницы с сохранением предыдущих сообщений.... Это возможно? Можете посоветовать что-нибудь умное... Может функции какие... Я совсем новичок, мне еще многое непонятно. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю задачу - возьмите исходники любого ajax- или java-чата...

Answer (score 0):

Общий для всех языков алгоритм будем примерно таким.

1. получить текст
2. Разбить текст в массив по символам
3. Циклом пробежаться по элементам массива заменяя каждый символ, на соответствующий сивол(ы) из латиницы
4. Соединить массив обратно в текст
5. Вывести результат

P.S. Это все что можно сказать по вашему вопросу, так как ни конкретно в чем у вас загвоздка, и о вашем языке программирования вы ни слова не написали.

Comment: аААА....Ну например с использованием только PHP и Html Это возможно?

Comment: А вообще с помощью каких языков это можно написать? Это же что-то вроде единоличного чата, да? Я, если совсем честно, вообще ничего не пойму) Только что и умею примитивную сайт-визитку написать( Так вот, вы не подскажите, какие языки надо использовать? Благодарю заранее)))))

Comment: Да в принципе любые, хоть brainfuck ;)
Вам видимо лучше всего сделать это в JavaScript

http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/5074-dinamichnaya-transliteraciya-rus-en.html#post30030

Comment: И да, HTML это НЕ язык программирования)))